# Ch376 USB Module with SPI

Tags: microcontroller, pic, spi, usb-host, module

What is the problem here, I used logic analyser to check the data and commands i send to the Ch376 USB Module, And all are right, But the module is not responding with any reply, Just return back the same data i send to the SPI register, I tried many connections to the module, Maybe there is a problem in the connection, Can any one help me to find out the problem, In the connection or the code?

Comment: There is an "air of mystery" from lack of details

Comment: I am sorry for this, What details do you need to know?

Comment: How about your design assumptions, datasheet link Ch376 USB Module https://www.mpja.com/download/ch376ds1.pdf , what tests worked, failed?  Signal integrity? etc etc  Sorry I cannot help you

Comment: http://pulko.mandy.pagesperso-orange.fr/shinra/CH376_ext.shtml

Comment: Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, providing more information. "I tried many connections": Please show us what you tried. "In the connection or the code?": Please show us the code. Our crystal balls are all in quarantaine, so we can't peek on your computer.